# Can't figure out how to add a zero to increment function

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

So I have a function that takes an array of numbers (e.g. `[7,4,5]`) and the function should increment it by one (so, `[7,4,6]`). I've built the function and it works! But I can't figure out this situation: `[1,9,9,9]` should become `[2,0,0,0]` but instead it's just `[2]`.

I've provided the function below. Any suggestions would be super helpful. I've really done a recursion but it seemed like a good idea.

```
function increment(arr){
  let num = arr.pop();
  if(num === 9){
    increment(arr);
  } else {
    arr.push(num + 1);
      console.log(arr);    
  }
}
```

Comment: How it should behave for `[9, 9, 9]` ?

Comment: [9,9,9] should become [1,0,0,0].

Comment: Ooooh I totally overlooked that. Ha. Hmm...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join the array values and then split them back up like this:

```js
function increment(arr) {
  let num = Number(arr.join(""));
  return String(num + 1).split("").map(Number);
}

console.log(increment([1, 9, 9, 9]));
```

Comment: Same problem as @Brian McCall, thi returns as string back instead of int. Which means you wouldn't be able to use it again without converting it back.

Comment: `console.log(newArr.map(Number));` and do not forget to return the manipulated `array`

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet Well, the function itself is actually returning undefined - however, even if it weren't, it doesn't matter, because `Number(arr.join(""))` will coerce it to a number, regardless of if the values in the array are strings or ints

Comment: @Rayon I wasn't sure whether to return new array or not, since OP did not have anything being returned in the original code. I will add it, though, as from a functional approach, it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

how about joining the array elements together then parsing int and adding 1 then casting it to a string and splitting the number into the array

```
var arr = [1,9,9];
numberString = arr.join('');
numberToIncrement = parseInt(numberString)+1;
arr = String(numberToIncrement).split('');
console.log(arr) // [2,0,0]
```

Comment: problem with this is that it returns string back instead of int. Which means you wouldn't be able to use it again without converting it back.

Answer (score 0):

First convert array to `Number` increment it by 1 and then convert it back to the `array`:

```js
var arr=[9,9,9];
function increment(){
var anum=Number(arr.join(""));//converting arr to number
anum++;     //incrementing the number
var newArr=anum.toString().split("")
alert(newArr); //final new array
}
increment();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight) and save the carry for unshifting.

It works for any sized arrays.

```js
function inc(array) {
    var carry = array.reduceRight(function (r, a, i, aa) {
            var v = a + r;
            aa[i] = v % 10;
            return Math.floor(v / 10);
        }, 1);
    carry && array.unshift(carry);
    return array;
}

console.log(inc([7, 4, 5]));
console.log(inc([1, 9, 9, 9]));
console.log(inc([9, 9, 9, 9, 9]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Can you please explain reduceRight :)

Comment: it is just the same as reduce, but it starts from the right side. the index goes from `array.length - 1` to zero.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to append a 0 after incrementing a 9.

```js
function increment(arr) { 
  if (!arr || !arr.length) return [1];

  let num = arr.pop();

  if (num === 9) {
    let newArr = increment(arr)
    newArr.push(0);
    return newArr;
  } else {
    arr.push(num + 1);       
  }
  
  return arr;
}

console.log(increment( [0] ));
console.log(increment( [1,9,9] ));
console.log(increment( [9,9,9,9] ));
```

Answer (score 0):

While the answers given so far are correct, their runtime is linearly dependent on the number of input elements = O(n). The following solution runs - on average - in constant time = O(1):

```js
// Increment array:
function increment(arr) {
  let carry = 1;
  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0 && carry > 0; --i) {
    arr[i] += carry;
    carry = Math.floor(arr[i] / 10);
    arr[i] %= 10;
  }
  while (carry > 0) {
    arr.unshift(carry % 10);
    carry = Math.floor(carry / 10);
  }
  return arr;
}

// Example:
console.log(increment([9, 9]));
```

The number of iterations of above for-loop converges towards 90 for n >> 50, thus it runs in constant time on average. Worst-case time complexity remains linear.